# How to install Guest addition in mac os as guest and windows machine as host?

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine

I am trying to copy contents from host machine to guest machine, But for copying I need to install Guest addition.

Or there is any other way to access host machine content on guest machine or vice-versa.

Thank you,

Comment: There are no guest additions for OS X running on Windows, as it's against Apple EULA & therefore unlicensed.

Comment: @Tetsujin, is it possible to access USB content data?

Comment: I've no idea, I only use licensed software.

Answer (score 5):

No, there are no guest additions available for Mac OS X on VirtualBox. However, you can get the "shared folders" using SMB. In order to do so you'll have to add a Host-Only adapter to your Mac VM and enable "File Sharing" in Mac System Preferences.

Afterwards you can access the share via the IP address that was assigned to the Host-Only adapter of the VM (check with "ifconfig" in terminal). Here's a [detailed walkthrough](https://blog.tomtasche.at/2017/04/setting-up-mac-os-x-in-virtualbox.html) for all this.

For USB-support you'll have to install the proprietary VirtualBox extension pack first in order to enable "USB 3.0 support" in your VM's settings.